# Can RNP AR APCH be defined as NPA or APV or PA?

Tags: navigation

How to define RNP AR APCH as a

> Non-Precision Approach / Approach with Vertical Guidance / Precision
>   Approach?

or it varies when complying with different standards just like RNP APCH?

or it's only a special navigation method?

A document published by Airbus Safety First says:

> RNP and RNP AR procedures allow crews to fly approaches using internal
>   and very accurate navigation tools, instead of traditionally using
>   external guidance aids. They also allow the replacement of visual and
>   circling approaches by instrument approaches, thereby enhancing the
>   safety of airline operations. **They are non-precision approaches
>   although they provide the crews with cues and procedures similar to
>   those used on precision approaches.**

Click here, the 
 2nd paragraph in  Introduction Part https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/app/themes/mh_newsdesk/documents/archives/performance-based-navigation-rnp-and-rnp-ar-approaches.pdf

How can it define RNP as only a NPA?

Comment: They are non-precision approaches with vertical guidance.  So, they would be considered an APV approach. From what I recall about ICAO Annex 10, only ILS and MLS are classified as a precision approach.  A PAR approach may also be considered a precision approach.

Comment: So there is no official document mentioning the classification of RNP AR APCH, and what we can only classify is whether it's using vertical guidance or not?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found "RNP AR APCH operations are classified as approach procedures with vertical guidance (APVs) in accordance with Annex 6 — Operation of Aircraft. This type of operation requires a positive vertical navigation (VNAV) guidance system for the final approach segment (FAS). Current RNP AR APCH implementations utilize a barometric vertical navigation system (BARO-VNAV) meeting specified airworthiness requirements. " in DOC9905 1.2.3 at ICAO. link here:<https://www.icao.int/Meetings/PBN-Symposium/Documents/9905_cons_en.pdf>